# Evolution operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, convolution

We call a function that assigns a starting value of a time-dependent differentialfunction to a solution of a later timevalue as the evolution operator $E(t)$.

Look at the thermal equation

$$
u_t=u_{xx},~~~u_0(x)=u(0,x)
$$

where $u\colon [0,T]\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with the evolution operator $E(T)u_0=u(T,0)$.

Show that $u_0\star G_t$ with

$$
G_t(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{t}\right)
$$
is a solution of the above equation.

Advice: You therefore have to show $E(T)u_0=u_0\star G_T$.

---

I am a little bit helpless.

Did I understand the evolution operator right, when thinking that

$E(T)(x)=u(T,0)$ for every $x$?

Then I have to show $(u_0\star G_T)(x)=u(T,0)$?

If yes: How can I do so? Does the Fourier transformation play any role? I thought of that because of the convolution but it was only a quick thought...

I would be very thankful if anyone could help me to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your suspicions are correct. Try the Fourier transform: if $U$ is the Fourier transform of $u$, then Fourier transforming your PDE yields:
$$ \frac{\partial U(k,t)}{\partial t} = -k^2 U(k,t) $$
See if you can work with this new PDE.

Note: I am use the convention that the Fourier transform is:
$$ U(k,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-ikx} u(x,t) \, dx$$

Comment: My problem is the following: I do not understand the advice... why does $E(T)u_0=u_0\star G_T$ proof, that $u_0\star G_t$ is a solution of (1)?

Comment: Thank you. As I said my problem is the advice. If I do not consider the advice and just see it as solving a differentialequation, i think i can handle it. But the advice confuses me... i do not know how to start with this advice...

Comment: When you solve for $U(k,t)$, you will obtain an expression that involves the Fourier transform of $u_0$. Then you can use the convolution identity when solving for $u$ by inverse Fourier transform, and you will get an expression of the desired form.

Comment: Hm, if i do so, i get $G_t(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-\lvert x^2\rvert/4t}$ and not $G_t(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-x^2/t}$

Comment: I got this: $\hat{u}(t,k)=\hat{u_0}e^{-\lvert k\rvert^2 t}$. Then with inverse formula $u(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{u_0}(k)e^{-\lvert k\rvert^2t}e^{ikx}\, dk$. Setting $\omega=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{-\lvert k\rvert^2 t})$, I got $u(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{(u_0\star \omega)}(k,t)e^{ikx}\, dk=(u_0\star \omega)(t,x)$. Then $\omega(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\lvert k\rvert^2 t}e^{ikx}\, dx=(4\pi t)^{-1/2}e^{-\lvert x\rvert^2/4t}$

Comment: Is it a mistake on the sheet, that $G_t(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{t})$ instead of $G_t(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{4t})$?

Comment: How can i show that $E(T)\colon L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1])$ is a compact operator and that $E(T)\colon L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a non-compact operator?

Comment: You may be right, there may be a typo. I don't have time to check this myself, I'm sorry. You could try checking your algebra on the computer just to be sure. As for your new question, you should post that as a separate question, I think.